# Contagem regressiva de dias a um evento futuro

Tags: php, mysql, contador

Um sistema que cadastra currículos, o currículo fica ativo por meses após a data de cadastro, que na minha tabela é a variável $row_curriculos['created'];

Consegui criar o php que diz a data que encerra o cadastro.

```
    <?php  
     $data = $row_curriculos['created']; 
     $timestamp = strtotime($data . "+6 months"); 
     echo date('d/m/Y', $timestamp);  
     ?>

Gostaria de exibir o numero de dias, exemplo:
Faltam XX dias para o cadastro expirar.

Tentei fazer assim:


  <?php
    $data = $row_curriculos['created'];
    $timestamp = strtotime($data . "+6 months");    
    $dia_hora_atual = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
    $dia_hora_evento = strtotime(date($timestamp));

    $diferenca = $dia_hora_evento - $dia_hora_atual;

    $dias = ($diferenca / 86400);
    echo "$dias dia(s)";
    ?>
```

Mas esta retornando os dias como -17336.

Comment: Não entendi o "Consegui criar o php que diz a data que encerra o cadastro."

Comment: Desculpa, consegui fazer exibir a data final que encera o cadastro, que é 6 meses depois data do cadastro `$row_curriculos['created'];`

Answer (score 2):

Seu erro está nesta linha:

```
$dia_hora_evento = strtotime(date($timestamp));
```

Você já tem o horário do evento, é o próprio `$timestamp`. Não precisa fazer nada em cima dele. Basta usá-lo diretamente na subtração:

```
$diferenca = $timestamp - $dia_hora_atual;
```

http://ideone.com/jXr0KV

Comment: ok, realmente não precisava usar o $dia_hora_evento, mas o erro continua, acho que é na variavel, que estão retornando a data com hora, `$row_curriculos['created']; = 19-06-2017:08:32:01`.
tentei varias opções de editar a variável, inserindo date(d-m-Y, $row_curriculos['created']);, mas não funcionou.

Se inserir a data por extenso funciona, mas usando a variável, não funciona.

Comment: Resolvido, no meu banco de dados estava o tipo coomo datetime, mudei para date e funcionou corretamente, da maneira que queria.